# Python regex, matching pattern over multiple lines.. why isn't this working?

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I know that for parsing I should ideally remove all spaces and linebreaks but I was just doing this as a quick fix for something I was trying and I can't figure out why its not working.. I have wrapped different areas of text in my document with the wrappers like "####1" and am trying to parse based on this but its just not working no matter what I try, I think I am using multiline correctly.. any advice is appreciated

This returns no results at all:

```
string='
####1
ttteest
####1
ttttteeeestt

####2   

ttest
####2'

import re
pattern = '.*?####(.*?)####'
returnmatch = re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE).findall(string)
return returnmatch
```

Comment: It won't run period because you're not using multi-line string symbols `'''` or `"""`

Comment: ok, I missed this concept completely then, i will dig through the re documentation to find where it mentions this.. thanks

Comment: Your assignment to `string` is a syntax error. Did you mean to use `'''`?

Comment: no I'm new to python so I didn't know about the mutline string delimiter

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try `re.findall(r"####(.*?)\s(.*?)\s####", string, re.DOTALL)` (works with `re.compile` too, of course).

This regexp will return tuples containing the number of the section and the section content.

For your example, this will return `[('1', 'ttteest'), ('2', '  \n\nttest')]`.

(BTW: your example won't run, for multiline strings, use `'''` or `"""`)

Comment: Thank you! Been searching for hours for "python find string between substrings" and nobody mentioned this. I knew it had to be a simple toggle of options since my logic was correct. Commenting this here so future searchers can find it.

Answer (score 28):

Multiline doesn't mean `.` will match line return, it means that `^` and `$` are limited to lines only

> re.M
>   re.MULTILINE
>
> When specified, the pattern character '^' matches at the beginning of the string and at the >beginning of each line (immediately following each newline); and the pattern character '$' >matches at the end of the string and at the end of each line (immediately preceding each >newline). By default, '^' matches only at the beginning of the string, and '$' only at the >end of the string and immediately before the newline (if any) at the end of the string.

`re.S` or `re.DOTALL` makes `.` match even new lines.

**Source**

[http://docs.python.org/](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.M)