# extract block of text from a file using python

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file and I want to extract a block of text from the starting point  till the ending point. The text file looks like below:

```
01.08.2016 00:00:00 ==================UK==========================
01.08.2016 09:15:34 Market : UK
01.08.2016 09:15:34 From : 01/07/2016
01.08.2016 09:15:34 To : 31/07/2016
01.08.2016 09:15:39 ==================GERMANY==========================
```

My starting point is `==================UK==========================` and ending point is  `==================GERMANY==========================`

Below is the code I have written but it does not seem to work.

```
import re

START = '==================UK=========================='
END = '==================GERMANY=========================='

fd = open('export_xml.log', 'r').read()

result = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (START,END), fd)

print result
```

Comment: `.` won't match newlines unless you set `re.DOTALL`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534507/python-regex-matching-pattern-over-multiple-lines-why-isnt-this-working, there are many more questions like that. The modifiers are also discussed in the [SO Regex Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/5138/regex-modifiers-flags#t=201608120804121686269).

Comment: Thanks Martijn, your answer helped. Thanks again.