# Regex for longest matching sequence between two strings

Tags: python, regex, string, pattern-matching, string-matching

I've searched Google for my use-case but didn't find anything much useful.

I am not an expert in regular expression so I would appreciate if anybody in the community could help.

**Question:**

Given a text file, I want to capture the longest string between two substrings (prefix and suffix) using regex. Note that those two substrings will always be at the start of any lines of the text. Please see the below example.

**Substrings:**

> prefixes = ['Item 1', 'Item 1a', 'Item 1b']
>   suffixes = ['Item 2', 'Item 2a', 'Item 2b']

**Example 1:**

> Item 1 ....
>   Item 2 ....
>   Item 1 ....
>   ....
>   ....
>   Item 2 ....
>   Item 1 ....
>   Item 2
>   Item 1a ....
>   ....
>   ....
>   ....
>   ....
>   Item 2b ....

**Expected Result:**

> Item 1a ....
>   ....
>   ....
>   ....
>   ....

**Why this result?**

Because prefix of `Item 1a` and suffix of `Item 2b` matches the longest string in the text between them of all other prefix-suffix pair.

**Example 2:**

> Item 1 ....
>   Item 2 ....
>   Item 1 ....
>   ....
>   ....
>   Item 2
>   .... 
>   Item 1 ....
>   Item 2
>   Item 1a .... 
>   ....
>   ....
>   ....
>   .... Item 2b
>   ....

**Expected result:**

> Item 1 ....
>   ....
>   ....

**Why this result?**

This is because this is the largest string between two strings (prefix and suffix pair) where both prefix and suffix starts at the beginning of the line. Note that there's another pair (`Item 1a`-`Item 2b`) but since `Item 2b` does not comes at the beginning of the line, we cannot consider this longest sequence.

**What I have tried with regex:**

I have tried with below regex for each prefix-suffix pair in my above list, but this didn't work.

```
regexs = [r'^' + re.escape(pre) + '(.*?)' + re.escape(suf) for pre in prefixes for suf in suffixes]
for regex in regexs:
    re.findall(regex, text, re.MULTLINE)
```

**What I have tried using non-regex (Python string functions):**

```
def extract_longest_match(text, prefixes, suffixes):
    longest_match = ''
    for line in text.splitlines():
        if line.startswith(tuple(prefixes)):
            beg_index = text.index(line)
            for suf in suffixes:
                end_index = text.find(suf, beg_index+len(line))
                match = text[beg_index:end_index]
                if len(match) > len(longest_match ):
                    longest_match = match
    return longest_match
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Regex can't match the longest substring. Use the regex or a non-regex solution to find the substrings and find the longest using the common language means.

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility to check length of string returned with regex. But do you know how to get text between prefix and suffix where both prefix and suffix start at the left side of sentence? Is my regex correct?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Regex can match the longest substring. The problem is that with `(.*?)` OP is explicitly using a non-greedy regex. Should probably only be `(.*)` instead of `(.*?)`.

Comment: @quant That `.*` won't yield the longest substring, that is just matching from the leftmost occurrence of the leading delimiter till the rightmost occurrence of trailing delimiter. And that is not the same. It is a common confusion of greediness and longest/shortest substring  extraction.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What am I missing here then? What's the correct regex to match string between prefix and suffix. I can then later check length and maintain largest string in a variable.

Comment: Surely you  miss `re.DOTALL`. You do not need `re.M` flag. And probably you want to match overlapping matches.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. How to do overlapping matches?

Comment: See [Python regex find all overlapping matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. I was trying with non-regex solution (using plain string functions) in Python. Please see the edited portion of questions. It is still not working correctly. Am I missing something there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

- Build a regex that matches strings from the leftmost starting delimiter to the leftmost trailing delimiter (see [Match text between two strings with regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680030/match-text-between-two-strings-with-regular-expression))
- Make sure the delimiters are matches [at the line start positions only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400362/using-to-match-beginning-of-line-in-python-regex)
- Make sure the `.` matches the line break chars by using `re.DOTALL` or equivalent options (see [Python regex, matching pattern over multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534507))
- Make sure the regex matches overlapping substrings (see [Python regex find all overlapping matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches))
- Find all matches in the text (see [How can I find all matches to a regular expression in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697882))
- Get the longest one (see [Python's most efficient way to choose longest string in list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873327)).

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/vywPEm):

```
import re
s="""Item 1 ....
Item 2 ....
Item 1 ....
....
....
Item 2 ....
Item 1 ....
Item 2
Item 1a ....
....
....
....
....
Item 2b ...."""
prefixes = ['Item 1', 'Item 1a', 'Item 1b']
suffixes = ['Item 2', 'Item 2a', 'Item 2b']
rx = r"(?=^((?:{}).*?^(?:{})))".format("|".join(prefixes), "|".join(suffixes))
# Or, a version with word boundaries:
# rx = r"(?=^((?:{})\b.*?^(?:{})\b))".format("|".join(prefixes), "|".join(suffixes))
all_matches = re.findall(rx, s, re.S | re.M)
print(max(all_matches, key=len))
```

Output:

```
Item 1a ....
....
....
....
....
Item 2
```

The regex looks like

```
(?sm)(?=^((?:Item 1|Item 1a|Item 1b).*?^(?:Item 2|Item 2a|Item 2b)))
```

With word boundaries

```
(?sm)(?=^((?:Item 1|Item 1a|Item 1b)\b.*?^(?:Item 2|Item 2a|Item 2b)\b))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pmTaoE/1).

**Details**

- `(?sm)` - `re.S` and `re.M` flags
- `(?=^((?:Item 1|Item 1a|Item 1b).*?^(?:Item 2|Item 2a|Item 2b)))` - a positive lookahead that matches at any location that is immediately followed with a sequence of patterns:

  - `^` - start of a line
  - `((?:Item 1|Item 1a|Item 1b).*?^(?:Item 2|Item 2a|Item 2b))` - Group 1 (this value is returned with `re.findall`)
  - `(?:Item 1|Item 1a|Item 1b)` - any of the items in the alternation (probably, it makes sense to add `\b` word boundary after `)` here)
  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
  - `^` - start of a line
  - `(?:Item 2|Item 2a|Item 2b)` - any alternative from the list (probably, it also makes sense to add `\b` word boundary after `)` here).

Comment: Thank you for your quick solution. One small issueI see on my test example (not shown here) is it also matches any suffixes which comes anywhere in the string. I want to check for such prefix-suffix pair where both prefix and suffix comes at the beginning of the line. Sorry if my example in the question mislead you to believe otherwise. :-)

Comment: I've edited my question with example 2. So maybe that example 2 will help to explain my use-case better :-)

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much!

Comment: @sgokhales Perhaps, you actually want `rx = r"(?=^((?:{})\b.*?^(?:{})\b))".format("|".join(prefixes), "|".join(suffixes))` to match the delimiters as whole words. See this [**Python demo**](https://ideone.com/52Xumx).

Comment: With your above regex in the comments, it throws me an error: max() arg is an empty sequence. Perhaps, it didn't find any match.

Comment: @sgokhales Sorry, forgot to use a raw string literal. Comment above is updated.

Comment: Also, thank you for all the reference links. It will definitely help to learn some regex'ing.