# How to match line beginning and end in a multi-line string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I would like to match entire line in a multi-line string (this code is part of unit test that checks the correct output format).

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r".*score = 0\.59.*", r"score = 0.65\nscore = 0.59\nscore = 1.0", re.MULTILINE)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 39), match='score = 0.65\\nscore = 0.59\\nscore = 1.0'>
```

This works fine, i can match anything within multiline string. However, i would like to make sure that i match entire line. The documentation sais that the `^` and `$` should match the beginning and end of line when `re.MULTILINE` is used. However, this somehow does not work for me:

```
>>> re.match(r".*^score = 0\.59$.*", r"score = 0.65\nscore = 0.59\nscore = 1.0", re.MULTILINE)
>>>
```

Here are a few more experiments i made:

```
>>> import os
>>> re.match(r".*^score = 0\.59$.*", "score = 0.65{}score = 0.59{}score = 1.0".format(os.linesep, os.linesep), re.MULTILINE)
>>>
>>> re.match(r".*^score = 0\.65$.*", "score = 0.65{}score = 0.59{}score = 1.0".format(os.linesep, os.linesep), re.MULTILINE)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 12), match='score = 0.65'>
>>> re.match(r".*^score = 0\.65$.*", r"score = 0.65\nscore = 0.59\nscore = 1.0", re.MULTILINE)
>>>
```

I guess i'm missing something rather simple, but couldn't figure that out.

Comment: try `flags=re.DOTALL`

Comment: chameleoned you

Comment: As of my understanding, you want to match the second line. Problem is that `.*` only matches one line excluding newline characters. You most likely want `re.DOTALL` in combination with a *lazy* quantifier (`.*?`).

Comment: drop the raw string: `re.match(r".*^score = 0\.65$.*", "score = 0.65\nscore = 0.59\nscore = 1.0", re.MULTILINE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem is that since you're using raw strings for your string, `\n` is seen as ... well `\` then `n`. Regexes will understand `\n` *in the pattern*, but not in the input string.

Also, even if not important there, always use `flags=` keyword, as some regex functions have an extra `count` parameter and that can lead to errors.

like this:

```
re.match(r".*^score = 0\.65$.*", "score = 0.65\nscore = 0.59\nscore = 1.0", flags=re.MULTILINE)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 12), match='score = 0.65'>
```

and as I noted in comments, `.*` needs `re.DOTALL` to match newlines

```
>>> re.match(r".*^score = \d+\.\d+$.*", "score = 0.65\nscore = 0.59\nscore = 1.0", re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 37), match='score = 0.65\nscore = 0.59\nscore = 1.0'>
```

(as noted in [Python regex, matching pattern over multiple lines.. why isn't this working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534507/python-regex-matching-pattern-over-multiple-lines-why-isnt-this-working) and [How do I match any character across multiple lines in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159118/how-do-i-match-any-character-across-multiple-lines-in-a-regular-expression) of which this *could* be a duplicate if it wasn't for the raw string bit)

(sorry, my floating point regex is probably a bit weak, you can find better ones around)

Comment: Yes, that seems to work. I messed up with raw vs. non-raw strings, and didn't notice the DOTALL option. Thank you, also for the extra suggestion!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes there were 2 issues. Raw strings & the DOTALL thing. Thanks. I answered only because of the raw string stuff, which isn't covered by the duplicate

Comment: I normally don't do that, but here I really don't understand that downvote spree so ok.

Answer (score 2):

You need to match against a non raw string *and* use DOTALL mode:

```
print re.match(r".*^score = 0\.59$.*", "score = 0.65\nscore = 0.59\nscore = 1.0",
    re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fd2426d0648>
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to work. I messed up with raw vs. non-raw strings, and didn't notice the DOTALL option. Thank you! Sorry that i cannot check two answers as "solved my problem"

Comment: @k6ps Wiktor duped your question, but he basically does that with every regex question, so don't feel bad about that.

Comment: at some point, when you're very much into a subject, everything is a dupe. But on that one, the raw string bit isn't covered.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Someone really needs to open up a broad discussion on the Meta site about this.  I will tell you that the duplicate threshhold on the SQL tag definitely seems to be substantially lower than regex.  The question is duplicate with respect to _which_ level of engineer?

Comment: I think I'm going to reopen it, quoting the links Wiktor left as dupes, because duplicate only answer partially (my first comment answered that already, then I found out the raw string bit) @TimBiegeleisen: reopened :)

Answer (score 1):

The real answer to your question is that you only confused `match` and `search`:

```
>>> import os, re
>>> print(re.match(r".*^score = 0\.59$.*", "score = 0.65\nscore = 0.59\nscore = 1.0", flags=re.MULTILINE))
None
>>> print(re.search(r".*^score = 0\.59$.*", "score = 0.65\nscore = 0.59\nscore = 1.0", flags=re.MULTILINE))
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(13, 25), match='score = 0.59'>
>>>
```

That's why one of your non-raw examples worked, while the other did not.